# XML Schema parsing [newbie]

Tags: xml, xsd

```
<log sessions="5" complete="5" timeouts="5" incomplete="5">
  <session>
    <event date="Fri Feb 1 05:31:18 GMT+0000 2013">LANDING_PAGE_CLICK</event>
    <event date="Fri Feb 1 05:31:39 GMT+0000 2013">TIMEOUT</event>
  </session>
</log>
```

I have the above XML.
How would I extract the date, and the "event" node? This is my first time writing an XSD I have came across this:

```
var dateString : String = response.status.@date;
var date : Date = DateFormatter.parseDateString (dateString);
```

but have no idea how this even fits into an XSD.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,James.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<xs:attribute name="lang" type="xs:string"/>
```

above is the code used to fix this problem.

EDIT: I have to rush home from work, but it's documented here
http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_simple_attributes.asp